# RabbitMQ multiple channels

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

Is it possible to have multiple categorized queues in RabbitMQ ?

Our application sends bulk SMS to phone numbers. when a client requests to send a very large number of SMSes , other normal client requests have to wait a lot. Is there a solution in RabbitMQ to have multiple queues ? ( So the worker can pick from all of them ? )

Answer (score 2):

Yes. it is possible to do in RabbitMQ.
Since you didn't provide enough details about your problem, I'l give you  a hight level overview of the things you might be interested in:

1. Take a look at [topic exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html). It does exactly what you described.
2. Take a look at [consumer priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html).
3. And [random exhcnage](https://github.com/simonmacmullen/random-exchange) that allows you to spread messages between queues.

Comment: Thanks. The topic is reall

Comment: If same user login from multiple devices then message get only one device.How can be solved it or any idea please?